# Reorder lines with a specific pattern in a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have a file that goes something like:

```
{{}} line 1
{{}} line 2
line 3
line 4
{{}} line 5
line 6
```

What I want to do is move the last line of the file prefixed by `{{}}` to be after the second to last line with `{{}}`, so the end result would be:

```
{{}} line 1
{{}} line 2
{{}} line 5
line 3
line 4
line 6
```

It has to be `bash` (calling `sed`, `perl`, `head`, or other commands, is fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk '$1!="{{}}"{move[++i]=$0;next}1 END{for(x=1;x<=length(move);x++)print move[x]}' file
```

Comment: @user137369 You're welcome. You can further shorten it to: `awk '$1!="{{}}"{move[++i]=$0;next}1 END{for(;x<length(move);)print move[++x]}' file`

Answer (score 3):

If line begins with `{{}}`, print it else save it for later,

```
perl -ne 'if (/^\Q{{}}/) {print}else{push @r,$_} }{print @r' file
```

Comment: It works to group them, but it’s moving the files with the prefix to the end of the file. How can I keep them at the top?

Comment: what you've got, lines with `{{}}` at the top or bottom?

Comment: I need the lines with `{{}}` to be grouped at the top. That command seems to be grouping them at the bottom.

Comment: @user137369 It does appear to be working just as your expected result show, i.e. group `{{}}` at the top. Is your sample data true representation of your actual data?

Comment: @user137369 if you want to reverse "groups", replace `if` with `unless`

Comment: The sample data is similar, the only difference is the lines contain a file path — I see that’s where the problem lies, since they start with `/`. Using `w` does nothing, but switching it to `{{}}` groups them at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -n 's/^\({{}}\)/\1/p;tk;H;:k;${x;s/\n//;p};d' file
```

---

```
$cat file
{{}} line 1
{{}} line 2
line 3
line 4
{{}} line 5
line 6

$sed -n 's/^\({{}}\)/\1/p;tk;H;:k;${x;s/\n//;p};d' file
{{}} line 1
{{}} line 2
{{}} line 5
line 3
line 4
line 6
```